# Given current position(Lat,Long,Alt), heading, pitch, velocity, and roll Calculate new Lat, Long,Alt

Tags: math, geolocation, gps, geospatial, dead-reckoning

Given Latitude, Longitude, Altitude, Velocity, Heading, Pitch and Roll, I want to calculate a new Latitude, Longitude and Altitude after x time of traveling at the same Heading, Pitch, Roll and Velocity.

I had already found great resources for solving this problems in 2 dimensions, but the new requirement for predicting future altitude has gotten me stumped.

[THIS](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/46505/how-to-calculate-altitude-in-a-flight-simulation/46508#46508) article claims that "You can't directly calculate the altitude of an aircraft from any set of control settings. The altitude is dependent on the history of the aircraft." However, I feel like I have a point in 3d space and I just want to slide it down a vector at velocity n for x amount of time and see where that position is.  But I don't know what that process is called as my math background is very weak.  If that article is true however, I don't mind extrapolating altitude, it just seems I can do better than extrapolation.

[Ted Hopp's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13712455/11752090) seems like exactly what I need, however, I don't quite understand how to make that "movement" piece he references here: toSpherical(***movement*** + toCartesian(lat, lng, alt)). I'm pretty sure I have all the pieces I need, I just need to move them.

Any resources or examples would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

A total list of params that I have is:

- velocityEast
- velocityNorth
- heading
- speed (velocity in the direction of heading is how I'm interpretitng this one)
- latitude
- longitude
- altitude
- heading
- radomeAzimuth
- pitch
- roll

I don't think I need to use all of these, but I'm trying to figure out the movement component of Ted Hopps answer: 
toSpherical(***movement*** + toCartesian(lat, lng, alt))

**Edit 2**

I think I found my movement vector [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=109069)

Where heading is my yaw
I'm going with it! Let me know if someone notices something blaringly wrong.

Comment: What don't you understand about Ted Hopp's answer, and what do you mean by "moving the [pieces of the] equation"?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog In his answer, in the final line he mentions "toSpherical(movement + toCartesian(lat, lng, alt))".  The 'movement' portion is what has me stumped about his answer.  I'm looking for a way to create movement with my given data.

Comment: `movement` is the *Cartesian* displacement vector that your object (aircraft?) moves by in one simulation timestep. Calculate the unit direction vector from [Heading, Pitch, Roll] (note that the roll has no effect) and multiply by the distance travelled (speed * timestep).

Comment: @meowgoesthedog thanks! I think I got it working