# How to calculate the bounding box around the touched map position?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2, bounding-box

In my Android application I want to request data for the location where the user **touches the map**. [`GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener.html) provides the touched position as latitude and longitude coordinates.

```
public abstract void onMapClick(LatLng point)
```

In order to pass an **area** instead of a point I need to calculate the coordinates for a bounding box **centered at the touch position**. The extend of the bounding box should **not** depend on the zoom level of the map.

I do **not** want to request the bounding box of the **visible screen** - just a small bounding box area around the touch position.

Is there any framework method I could use? Otherwise, how do I find a suitable **distance value** for the extend of the bounding box?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't [LatLngBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.html) what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can override `onMarkerClick` like below

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

    if (markerClicked) {

        if (polygon != null) {
            polygon.remove();
            polygon = null;
        }

        polygonOptions.add(marker.getPosition());

        polygonOptions.strokeColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorRedTransparent));
        polygonOptions.fillColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorBlueTransparent));

        polygonOptions.strokeWidth(5.0f);
        polygon = mMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
        polygon.setClickable(true);

    } else {
        if (polygon != null) {
            polygon.remove();
            polygon = null;
        }

        polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions().add(marker.getPosition());
        markerClicked = true;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Pass your polygon to generate bounding box

```
public static Rectangle getBoundingBox(Polygon polygon) {

    double boundsMinX = Double.MAX_VALUE; // bottom south latitude of the bounding box.
    double boundsMaxX = Double.MIN_VALUE; // top north latitude of bounding box.

    double boundsMinY = Double.MAX_VALUE; // left longitude of bounding box (western bound).
    double boundsMaxY = Double.MIN_VALUE; // right longitude of bounding box (eastern bound).

    for (int i = 0; i < polygon.getPoints().size(); i++) {
        double x = polygon.getPoints().get(i).latitude;
        boundsMinX = Math.min(boundsMinX, x);
        boundsMaxX = Math.max(boundsMaxX, x);

        double y = polygon.getPoints().get(i).longitude;
        boundsMinY = Math.min(boundsMinY, y);
        boundsMaxY = Math.max(boundsMaxY, y);
    }
     //Rectangle(double left, double bottom, double right, double top)
     return new Rectangle(boundsMinY, boundsMinX, boundsMaxY, boundsMaxX);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but usually screen-to-map coordinates are done using a few methods, probably something like that:

[Projection projection = googleMaps.getProjection();](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getProjection())

```
Point p = projection.toScreenLocation(point);
LatLng topLeft = projection.fromScreenLocation(new Point(p.x - halfWidth, p.y - halfHeight));
LatLng bottomRight = projection.fromScreenLocation(new Point(p.x + halfWidth, p.y + halfHeight));
```

**Edit:**

on the above

- `point` is the `LatLng` you received on your `onMapClick`.
- `p` is the on screen position of said click event
- `p.x - halfWidth`, `p.y - halfHeight`, `p.x + halfWidth`, `p.y + halfHeight` is a bounding box around the click location with `2 * halfWidth` of width and `2 * halfHeight` of height.
- `topLeft` and `bottomRight` is a bounding box around the click event in Latitude-Longitude coordinates.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are referring to the dimensions of the visible screen. That is not want I want. I want to calculate a bounding box around the touch position.

Comment: is the bound box specified in pixels or in meters?

Comment: But what is the value of `halfWidth`? That is the problem I am facing.

Comment: It's the number of pixels you want your box to be.

Comment: @Budius I am not sure I want to express the dimensions of the box in pixels. I rather want to express them in "ground units" (such as meters or centimeters), which is difficult to do since coordinates come in WGS84.

Comment: @JJD it's a bit more complex, but not impossible. That will narrow down pretty much to a math/geometry question than directly Android related. You probably will be interested in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837872/calculate-distance-in-meters-when-you-know-longitude-and-latitude-in-java and that https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double, double, double, double, float[]) . Possibly will use a interative approach (loop) or calculate the inverse of that equation to find out Meters-to-Degrees on that location.

Comment: @JJD this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857523/calculate-latitude-and-longitude-having-meters-distance-from-another-latitude-lo seems to be calculating what u need.